# Nodejs bot return 404 when deployed to Azure app service

Tags: node.js, azure, botframework

I tried to run the bot and deploy it to azure: https://github.com/microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples/tree/main/samples/javascript_nodejs/05.multi-turn-prompt

I followed this doc to do deployment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/provision-and-publish-a-bot?view=azure-bot-service-4.0&tabs=multitenant%2Cjavascript

After setup the identity, the bot works well locally, but when I test it from web chat, there is no response, and if I access by https://0915-bots-app-service.azurewebsites.net/api/messages I got this error: **The resource you are looking for has been removed, had its name changed, or is temporarily unavailable.**
I suspect this is caused by the generated **web.config file**, but seems there is no issue in it.

[picture from wwwroot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PWL7P.png)

The MicrosoftAppId and password are set correctly for both the Azure bot and app service.

Does anyone have some clue? Thanks!

Comment: It's hard to tell what might be wrong. There are plenty of steps in the publishing docs where a mistake may have been made. If you test in web chat in the Azure Portal, do you get a response? What error messages appear there?

Comment: Hi @AP01, thanks for your reply. When I tested in Azure portal, I did not get a response, I typed message into the chat but no response. Then I pasted the URL in browser and I get:  The resource you are looking for has been removed, had its name changed, or is temporarily unavailable.

Comment: Hi @AP01, is there a video I can follow to do the deployment although I have tried the deployment process multiple times. I tried to search such videos but did not find. I also see there are several posts/questions mentioned such 404 issue but no clear answer. It would be greatly helpful if there are such kind of videos. https://github.com/microsoft/botbuilder-dotnet/issues/2358

Comment: Unfortunately, there are no videos that run through the steps. The deployment steps change often as Azure teams make changes, and videos would often be out of date. As difficult as it might sound, your best bet is read the deployment steps very carefully and make sure you don't miss anything. You might also try a `Multi Tenant` bot instead of a managed identity if you haven't already. It's easier to get working.